# Html formatted text in NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm using a `NumberPicker` and I want to add a suffix for each number.

I know that I can do this:

```
picker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(int value) {
        return value + " suffix");
    }
});
```

But I want the suffix to be a subscript. So I tried this:

```
picker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(int value) {
        return value + " " + Html.fromHtml("<sub>suffix</sub>")
    }
});
```

But it's not working - the format is not applied; the suffix is not a subscript. That's obviously because `fromHtml` returns `Spanned` and then I'm converting it to `String`.

So can I apply an Html formatted string on the picker?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom `NumberPicker` and override `addView` methods:

```
@Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if(view instanceof TextView){
            your_spanned_string = ...;
            ((TextView) view).setText(your_spanned_string);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working... The string isn't affected. It still displays my `min` and `max` values even if I do `((TextView) view).setText("new text")`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Used this code to change styles of texts in picker and without second thought applied it to your case. After looking through `NumberPicker`'s code (`v23`), I can tell that there is no direct way to set spanned text to it, cause it operates solely on `String`s.

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is to not call `super.addView` in overriden `addView()`, but to replace it with your `CustomTextView`, copying stuff like `LayoutParams` and `text` from original. And in your `CustomTextView` override `setText(String text)` with new method that parses given `text` as `html`